# Communicating over XPC with an app and launch daemon running as root

Tags: macos, daemon, xpc

Is it possible to communicate with a launch daemon running as root and an application over XPC? When my daemon is running as my user I can communicate with it fine, when run as root it stops receiving my messages. Is this intended security inside Mac OS X?
I need to use low level xpc (for running on Lion as well). I know I can create a priviliged and signed helper tool that is running as root for my app. Will I be able to communicate with it with another process as well over XPC or sockets?

Thanks!

Small extract from my daemon code:

```
int main()
{
    Logger::Start(Poco::Path::expand("/Users/Shared/Me/Service.log"));
    Logger::LogInfo("Starting xpc_main...");

    void* observer = nullptr;
    CFStringRef observedObject = CFSTR("com.me.service.close");
    CFNotificationCenterRef center = CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter();
    CFNotificationCenterAddObserver(center, observer, notificationCallback, CFSTR("ClientClosing"), observedObject, CFNotificationSuspensionBehaviorDeliverImmediately);

    xpc_connection_t listener = xpc_connection_create_mach_service("com.me.service", NULL, XPC_CONNECTION_MACH_SERVICE_LISTENER);
    xpc_connection_set_event_handler(listener, ^(xpc_object_t event)
    {
        // New connections arrive here. You may safely cast to
        // xpc_connection_t. You will never receive messages here.
        // The semantics of this handler are similar to those of
        // of the one given to xpc_main().
        Logger::LogInfo("Event Handler on listener is called");

        eventHandler((xpc_connection_t)event);
    }); 

    Logger::LogInfo("call xpc_connection_resume...");

    xpc_connection_resume(listener);

    CFRunLoopRun();

    Logger::LogInfo("Main Program is Exiting...");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have any ideas? XPC is not required, just want to have a global daemon running which will be able to communicate with 2 processes.

Comment: Not an idea, but I am currently in a similar situation, and was wondering if you could provide guidance.... I need a way for an event to launch my daemon process. What I mean is I have a website, that when a BTN click occurs, I want to send a message to the daemon to execute. Any ideas or suggestions would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that **CFNotificationCenterGetDistributedCenter** works only on the same user, root user will not send message to other logged in users..

You'll need to switch to **CFNotificationCenterGetDarwinNotifyCenter**.

Please note however, that you can't pass any data using this center.