# Recommended way to stream data from one process to another in macOS?

Tags: swift, cocoa, notifications

I do have a helper application which generates data which I need in my main application.
I'm searching for a way to push this data to the main app.

One way would be DistributedNotificationCenter.
The documentation says that notifications will be dropped if there are too many, but I cannot find a recommendation what the maximum suggested notifications are.
Currently I need to send an array with about 100 entries about 5-10 times a second.
If this is not a suggested way what would be a better one?

Comment: I must admit that I have not worked with this myself but could you use XPC for this maybe? Here is a description from Apple: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingXPCServices.html and here is an article from objc.io: https://www.objc.io/issues/14-mac/xpc/  Hope it helps you.

Comment: This would be a quite perfect way with only one problem: My helper app needs root access and as far as I can see in the docs "Elevating a service’s privileges to root is not supported" :(

Comment: ah yes..that seems kind of a deal breaker I agree :( Don't know if this answer gives you anything: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23552805/communicating-over-xpc-with-an-app-and-launch-daemon-running-as-root but apart from that...I have nothing further sorry. Good luck and I hope you find a solution.

Comment: Hm using NSTask to run the helper could also work but only if there is a way to get complete array objects in kind of a "stream" but I'm not sure if this is possible